# Linq way to check if any other element matches expression while skipping itself

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda

In my project I'm organizing cells (TextBlock controls, in my case) into Lists called boxes. Every box has 9 cells. Is there a way to compare all of the cell elements in those lists and return true if *any* of them match whatever expression I specify? For each comparison I make as I'm iterating through the list of cells, I need to ensure that the given cell will not consider itself when making comparisons. This way, it rightfully won't consider its own value, hence the lambda statement I've attempted to write below. I know that First() and Single() return single elements, so I suspect it's my lambda that's causing the problem. I'm using the following code:

```
while (cell.Text == box.SkipWhile(e => e == cell).First().Text)
{
    // change cell.Text's value here as long as any other cell's
    // .Text value is the same
}
```

Even though this compiles, stepping through the code seems to skip the while statement more often than it should and I'm still getting identical .Text values between cells in the same box.

Comment: Your specification is very unclear. "... to compare between all elements in a list..." Any List? or your List of Boxes? or maybe your collection of Cells of which we didn't know yet that is was a List? "... match the expression..." Which expression? Any expression? "... make exception for the cell itself ..."  Does the expression mention a cell as input? "It doesn't count if Text.Value == itself", If itself is a cell, does that mean that Text.Value is also a Cell? Please reconsider writing a proper specification

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse Thanks, I've edited the initial post in an attempt to be more clear. For now, juharr's answer was sufficient for my needs but any other ideas are always welcome. Let me know if I need to clarify further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any` like this.  That will tell you if box contains something with the same `Text` value, but where it isn't the same item as `cell` (presumably by reference, but that depends on what `cell` is)

```
if(box.Any(e => e.Text == cell.Text && e != cell)){
    cell.Text = somethingDifferent;
}
```